Achievement Banner Not Shown
Achievement added successfully on players Game Center,user can see it on gamecenter platform
but while unlocking the achievement the banner is not visible on the screen,
I use unity platform for macOS
Here my code ;
public class Achievement
{
    public AchievementType Type;
    public int Value;
    public string ID;
    
    public Achievement(AchievementType type, int value, string id)
    {
        Type = type;
        Value = value;
        ID = id;
    }
    
    public async void Unlock()
    {
        var achievements = await GKAchievement.LoadAchievements();
        var achievement = achievements.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Identifier == ID);
        achievement ??= GKAchievement.Init(ID);
        Debug.Log("Achievement will be unlocked" + ID);
        Debug.Log("Last Reported Date " + achievement.LastReportedDate);
        if (!achievement.IsCompleted)
        {
            Debug.Log("Achievement Unlocked" + ID);
            achievement.PercentComplete = 100;
            achievement.ShowCompletionBanner = true;
            GKAchievement[] achieves = {achievement};
            await GKAchievement.Report(achieves);
            Debug.Log("Achievement Reported" + ID);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Achievement Already Unlocked" + ID);
        }
       
    }

}

I try to unlock achievement by shown banner, achievement unlocked but banner not visible on the screen
